# Point of continuity of separately continuous functions

Tags: gn.general-topology

Let $X,Y$ be completely regular Baire spaces. Is it true that every real valued separately continuous function on $X\times Y$ has a point of continuity?

Comment: Real valued function?

Comment: Yes. Thank you for the question. Real or complex valued. I modify the text accordingly.

Comment: @DieterKadelka: I think it's worthwhile to point out that if it is true for real-valued functions, then it is also true for all functions with values in completely regular (Hausdorff) spaces (since closed sets and points in such spaces can be separated by continuous real-valued functions).

Comment: Concering the questions itself: This sounds rather strong to me. There's a famous theorem of Ellis which says that if $(G,\circ)$ is a group, $G$ is endowed with a compact Hausdorff topology and $\circ$ is separately continuous, then $\circ$ is automatically jointly continuous. The assertion in your question would immediately yield Ellis' theorem as a special case (by using the observation from my previous comment).

Comment: You probably know this already, but there are no counterexamples with metrizable $X$ and $Y$

Comment: Also you might be interested in Namioka's paper "Separate continuity and joint continuity"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A counterexample to this problem (with $X$ Baire and $Y$ compact) was recently constructed by Mykhaylyuk and Pol in [this preprint](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1809.05799.pdf).

Comment: Thank you very much. This clearly answers even a stronger question.